# Program to swap row that contains the smallest number with row that contains the biggest number in a twodimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, swap

I am trying to create a program that swaps the row that contains the min number with the row that contains the max number in a n x m twodimensional array (c++)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m, imin, imax, jnm, jnv;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int k[n][m];

    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]" << endl;
            cin >> k[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << endl
         << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << k[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl
         << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

            if (k[i][j] > max) {
                max = k[i][j];
                imax = i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    min = max;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

            if (k[i][j] < min) {
                min = k[i][j];
                imin = i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl
         << endl;
    if (imax == imin) {
        cout << endl
             << "Min & Max are in the same row!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (i == imax) {
                    k[i][j] = k[imin][j];
                }
                else if (i == imin) {
                    k[i][j] = k[imax][j];
                }
                cout << k[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know the code isn't the cleanest and most professionally written, and that isn't important, as I'm currently preparing for a coding competition where the only thing that matters is functionality of the program.

When I execute this program, it usually swaps one row but the other is still the same.

Comment: Well, what did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? [Edit] your question, and tell us about that debugging session, please!

Comment: You are essentially trying to swap `a` and `b` by doing `a = b; b = a;` It should be obvious why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use function `swap`if you want to swap. At the moment you assignments are wrong.

So, simply write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m, imin=0, imax=0;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int>> k(n, vector<int>(m, 0));
    
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]" << endl;
            cin >> k[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << endl
        << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << k[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl
        << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

            if (k[i][j] > max) {
                max = k[i][j];
                imax = i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    min = max;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

            if (k[i][j] < min) {
                min = k[i][j];
                imin = i;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl
        << endl;
    if (imax == imin) {
        cout << endl
            << "Min & Max are in the same row!" << endl;
    }
    else {

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            swap(k[imin][j], k[imax][j]);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                cout << k[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And sorry, I cannot write `int k[n][m];` because this is not C++ and my compiler cannot compile it. But vector can be used in the same way.

If you are not allowed to use `std::swap`you can use instead:

```
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            int tmp = k[imin][j];
            k[imin][j] = k[imax][j];
            k[imax][j] = tmp;
        }
```

---

For the competition you could also get the min and max values already during input and write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    // Read matrix size
    size_t rows{}, columns{};
    if (std::cin >> rows >> columns) {

        // Here we will store our matrix
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(rows, std::vector<int>(columns, 0));

        // Initilize min max values
        int maxElement = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
        int minElement = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        size_t indexMaxRow{}, indexMinRow{};

        // Enter values in matrix
        for (size_t row{}; row < rows; ++row) {
            for (size_t column{}; column < columns; ++column) {
                std::cout << "array[" << row << "][" << column << "]\n";
                if (std::cin >> matrix[row][column]) {

                    // Already during input find the min and max values
                    if (matrix[row][column] > maxElement) {
                        maxElement = matrix[row][column];
                        indexMaxRow = row;
                    }
                    if (matrix[row][column] < minElement) {
                        minElement = matrix[row][column];
                        indexMinRow = row;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Show original matrix
        std::cout << "\n\n\nYou entered:\n\n";
        for (const auto& row : matrix) {
            for (const auto& col : row) std::cout << col << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        // Swap
        std::swap(matrix[indexMaxRow], matrix[indexMinRow]);

        // Show swapped matrix
        std::cout << "\n\n\nSwapped:\n\n";
        for (const auto& row : matrix) {
            for (const auto& col : row) std::cout << col << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError while reading size\n";
}
```